# jQuery selector intermittent working, why?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I simply want to manipulate the elements within the `#content` div, but `$('#content')` doesn't seem to work, and yet in other places it does! My relevant code is very simple:

### HTML

```
<body>
  <input type='button' value='Save design' id='save'  />
  <div id="content" style="height: 200px; width:600px;border: 1px solid black;" class='whatev'></div>
</body>
```

### Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('#save').click(function(e){
     alert( document.getElementById('content').id); // this works!
     alert($("#content").length); // this works! it outputs "1"
     alert($("#content").id); // this does NOT work - undefined, why?
     //end save function
   });

    $('#content').click(function(e){ 
       // do stuff // ALL of this works!
    });
});
```

That is it. If you notice, it does work in some places (the entire click function bound to it is perfectly fine), but where it doesn't work, it strangely does still exist because `length = 1`. I tried using context as well to search the div, just in case, (using `$('#content','body')`), but no use.

Comment: `$("#content").id`? Why? Do you really need the `ID` when you have selected the element based on it's `ID` property?

Comment: no I didn't really need the ID, I needed other attributes, was only using the ID as a test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a difference between a DOM element and a jQuery selection that contains a DOM element. A jQuery selection is a wrapper around the DOM object to make it easier to use. It doesn't have an `id` property, but a DOM element does. On the other hand, jQuery does provide a way to access elements' properties using the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method:

```
document.getElementById('content').id // access the id property of a DOM element
$('#content').attr('id')              // use jQuery to select the element and access the property
```

The `length` property, however, is provided by a jQuery selection, which is why that works fine for you.

Comment: You should use `.attr()` for the ID. `.prop()` is for specific things as described in the docs at http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @JAAulde [Apparently so](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/), even if that is a ridiculous design decision. jQuery's worst, IMO.

Answer (score 10):

`id` is a plain DOM property/attribute, and works with plain DOM objects, not jQuery objects.

You would do this in jQuery:

```
$("#content").attr('id');
```

which equals:

```
document.getElementById('content').id
```

or

```
$("#content")[0].id; //[0] gets the first DOM object in the collection
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("#content").attr("id")
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this, because it is reasonably correct, but could you not have explained this a little more?

Answer (score 3):

`$("#content")` returns the jQuery collection containing the elmenent with id `content`. `id` is an attribute of an element, not a property of the collection. You would get the element's ID by chaining the `attr()` method off the collection:

```
alert($("#content").attr('id'));
```

Or, when `each`ing the collection, inside the function passed to `each` `this` will be the actual element, so you could access `this.id`

```
$("#content").each(function () {alert(this.id);});
```

Answer (score 2):

For this question you should go straight to jsfiddle, and to the jquery docs for how to get attributes of html elements -> http://api.jquery.com/attr/.

The jQuery selector object itself doesn't have an attribute `id`.  You have to use `.attr('id')` function.

I fixed that and everything else works, as you see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AdtrX/1/

Answer (score 2):

Always remember!

In jQuery when you want to access some `attribute` of the selected element, you use `jQuery`'s
`.attr()` API.

Now you said this,
`document.getElementById("content").id` Works,
Equivalent `jQuery` statement of this line is

`$("#content").attr('id');`

For selecting attribute use `.attr()`
For manipulating style/css use `.css()`

YOu can also alter CSS properties of the selected element using `.attr()`

Like `.attr('style','your new style');`

Comment: Thats one of the most confusing things about jQuery, especially if you are starting out... :)

Answer (score 2):

you can get id by by using .attr("id") function.
Use this code:
***$("#content").attr("id");***

Answer (score 2):

what led me to this page is

I have this div with id `LING_a_00224.s03`

```
<div id="LING_a_00224.s03" ></div>
```

and when I use jquery selector to get it

```
$("#LING_a_00224.s03")
```

I got `not element` (jquery selector not working)

thats because the `dot (.)` in `the id`

jquery will `interpret` it as  All elements with `id="LING_a_00224" and class="s03"`, not All elements with `id="LING_a_00224.s03"`

> so make sure that id selector does not contains jquery selector symbols like (`.`)

or 
if you `don't have control` over elements  `ids`, you can do

```
selector=document.getElementById("LING_a_00224.s03");//JQuery selector sometimes fails because id may contains dot on it like #fn12.e2e
$(selector).jqueryFunction()// wrap the JavaScript object into $() to convert it to jquery object
```

hope this helps you