# #id selector not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

This is probably a triviality, but I cannot manage to make this simple code work. The bits of interest are reported below.

```
<script>
    $("#link1").click(function(){
        $("#content").fadeOut(200);
    });
</script>

[....]

<nav>   
    <a class="navLink" id="link1">Link1</a>
    <a class="navLink" id="link2">Link2</a>
    <a class="navLink" id="link3">Link3</a>
    <a class="navLink" id="link4">Link4</a>
</nav>                   

<div id="container">    
    <div id ="content">            
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div>        
</div>
```

The idea is to make the div "content" disappear when clicking on Link1. But it just does not happen. Interestingly, if I replace the script as shown below and add a onclick event trigger to Link1 then it works.

```
<script>
    function disappear(){
        $("#content").fadeOut(200);
    }
</script>
```

This suggests that the `#id` selector actually works (at least for "content"). Does anyone see where the issue is in my code?

Thank you in advance,
ETtore

Comment: You need to wrap your jQuery in a [`$(document).ready()` block](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), otherwise you're running the code before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: or add the `script` element below your `a` elements

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44351803/4251431

Answer (score 1):

Your script appears before the element it requires (`#link1`), therefore it can't find it yet.

You either need to move your script further down the page, or wrap it in `$(function() {...})`

Comment: Thank you! I actually realised that just moments after posting my question... :-)
Wrapping the script into $(window).ready(...) is also an option as Sachin suggests.

Comment: `$(function() {...})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {...});` ;)